# Concept about ENCAPSULATION

Tags: c#, oop, encapsulation

I am very confused about encapsulation. My current concept of encapsulation is that it is only used for data hiding.

My code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Shape a;
            a= new Shape();
            a.Area = 4;
            Console.WriteLine(a.Area);
        }
    }

    class Shape
    {
        private int _area = 0;
        private int _parameter = 0;
        public int Area { get; set; }
        public int Parameter { get; set; }

    }
```

From what I understand, the private int variable `_area` is now encapsulated. So, what encapsulation is doing here is by
using private access modifier, I can hide this variable; and
by using public property, I can initialize this variable without
using the class variable.

Is this what encapsulation is all about? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385361/what-are-the-different-types-of-encapsulation (other than the top answer).

Comment: As a side note: your variabel `_area` will never be used. When using autoproperties (the `{get; set;}` syntax), the backingfiled is created automaticallly *behind the scene*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use properties when no logic is involved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165326/why-use-properties-when-no-logic-is-involved)

Comment: @Koen, what that backingfield is supposed to do?

Comment: Write a `class CalenderDate` without encapsulation (`public int Y,M,D;`) and then try to guarantee, as the writer of the class, that the instances will always contain a valid date.

Comment: Have a read about the [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). If you still have a question regarding them, I suggest to open a new question for that.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just **Information Hiding**

**Encapsulation** means that a group of related properties, methods, and other members are treated as a single unit or object.

According to the principle of encapsulation, a class or struct can specify how accessible each of its members is to code outside of the class or struct. Methods and variables that are not intended to be used from outside of the class or assembly can be hidden to limit the potential for coding errors or malicious exploits.

Comment: Helping against coding errors - Yes. But you won't stop any "malicious exploits" with encapsulation.

Comment: @Rajesh, so here my code is not implementing the concept of ENCAPSULATION you mean to say?

Comment: Now both Area and parameter is public, that means that there no protection or limitation for outside uses. If your system needs some protection  like only Area can be exposed and parameter should be exposed only to same assembly u can make protected set for Parameter.. In this case, it is encapsulated

Comment: @Henk Malcious exploits can be avoided if we use encapsulation sensibly, if you are having a class that has public property of Connection string, it can exploited for sql server connection details

Comment: Encapsulation is absolutely not about security. That is a misconception. Many ways around it, Reflection being the easiest.

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian what do you mean by this statement of yours:
a GROUP of related properties, methods, and other members

Comment: @AbidAli It means that a package or class that contains it own properties , methods and others related to it .